# Dynamically add FormArray to a FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'd like to dynamically add a FormArray, this is my form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   workFlowId: ['', Validations.required]
})
```

In my UI, the user will have to write inside an input the workFlowId, and then I'd like to add a new FormArray to the form with the workFlowId as the key of the FormArray.

The result of the form should be something like this:

> {"workFlowId": 123,"123":[{"key":"username", "value": "mor"}]}

Is it possible to do such thing? if so, how will it look in the HTML?

Comment: do you want to add an array in a form group.?

Comment: Yes, but I want to add it dynamically after the user entered something in other input and have the input as the key for that array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function when adding new arrayForm to your form:

```
(this.form.get('workFlowId') as FormArray).push(new FormGroup({
      'key' : new FormControl('username'),
      'value': new FormControl('mor')
}))
```

Your additional input form:

```
<form [formGroup]="inputForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input [formControlName]="input1">
<input [formControlName]="input2">
</form>
```

Your controller:

```
/* Additional formGroup definition */
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   input1: ['']
   input2: ['']
})

/* Submitting function to transfer data from inputform to destination array form */
onSubmit() {
(this.form.get('workFlowId') as FormArray).push(new FormGroup({
      'key' : new FormControl(inputForm.get('input1').value),
      'value': new FormControl(inputForm.get('input2').value)
}))
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this code will push an object to an existing array, and not make a new array with the key entered in 'workFlowId'

Comment: Yes, correct. You can use above function in `onSubmit` of the other form you wish to push those data into array, i.e. `(click)="createNewFormArrayEntry($event)"` to transfer data between one form to formArray